is there a way to set spinner background properly in android studio?
i did put a Spinner in my app so that the user can select and change the language. when i want to set the background of my dropDown, there is a white line on the top and bottem of my dropDown list.


i tried using a custom layout for my DropDownViewResource:
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item)
where my spinner_dropdown_item.xml file is like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:background="@color/background"/>

2.I tried setting padding and margin to 0dp
3.and i did try to set popUpbackground in my activity layout
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:popupBackground="@color/background"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


Can you try setting the background property of the spinner along with popupBackground

i tried but it didn't work
